# Prevent jspm from require'ing a module

Tags: javascript, require, jspm

In a JS file being loaded by JSPM/System.js I have

```
if ( condition )
   require( "file" )
```

My problem is jspm always tries to load `"file"` regardless of `condition` and `"file"` doesn't exist in specific scenarios. Which results in `Uncaught (in promise) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)` and I can't find a way to handle the promise.

Note that this file is used in the Browser with jspm and on Node without jspm.

Answer (score 0):

Requires are parsed (and resolved) even before the file is executed, so conditions wont help you there.

You can, however, use Systemjs directly to load the module:

```
if (condition) {
    System.import('file');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of ```System.import()``` however on Node.js I'm not using jspm as I mentioned, so ```System.import()``` won't be available there.

I've been able to work around using:
```require( condition ? file : '' )```
however I'm surprised this works because as you say require's are statically parsed.